# Excel compound if condition to an arbitrary length

Tags: excel, if-statement

I have position, time, lat, long, velocity and elevation data for a train.
My problem is that i want to remove the data points where the train has stopped, this would include the deceleration and acceleration measurements. The idea is to compare a number of trains travelling the same path under optimum conditions, ie not stopping. The measurements show the trains stopping at different times and locations. I currently check if the previous location is the same and then check if the speed is less than 50% of the previous 3 values. The problem is if more than the previous 3 values are o or less than 50% of the previous kept speed, then i dont remove all the required data, such as the train accelerating back up to speed, such as U60 below.

Here is the the eqn is U60

```
=IF(P60=P59,"removed",IF(S60<(0.5*S59),"removed",IF(U59="removed",IF(S60<(0.5*S58),"removed",IF(S60<(0.5*S57),"removed",P60)),P60)))
```

The only way i can think of to catch this is to have multiple nested conditions (upto 20) to catch all the points. This may not be enough for some trains.

Is there a way to remove the deceleration and acceleration points (this may be 2 or 3 points) without having to have ~20 nested conditions?

[image]

Comment: The values in column S seem to transition within two or three rows. Couldn't you base your calculation against the average of the last 5 or so rows of values?

Comment: Unfortunately, the points during acceleration are still not caught with this calculation. Its definitely a cleaner approach though, Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After using the solution from @user3819867 for a while, we have determined that it is not sufficient because we can not capture the real points of deceleration or acceleration without manually finding them.

However, we have come up with a solution which should prove adequate. The solution is to linearly interpolate between successive peaks in the velocity. This should only happen if the train (vehicle) has stopped. In order to do this I needed to calculate the Slope of each point, determine if the point was a local peak, determine the locations of the previous and next peak, then determine the X and Y coordinates of those peaks to perform the interpolation from.

Here is a brief overview of the eqns and what the spreadsheet looked like.

```
Slope of velocity line  
=IFERROR(SLOPE(AH2:AH3,AD2:AD3),"") 
local peak
=IF(AND(AM4>0,AM3<0),"peak","")     
REPLACE
=IFERROR(MATCH(0,INDIRECT("AH"&AP3):INDIRECT("AH"&AQ3),0),"")   
previous peak
=SUMPRODUCT(MAX(($AN$3:AN3="peak")*(ROW($AN$3:AN3))))   
next peak
=MATCH("peak",AN4:$AN$453,0)+ROW(AN3)   
new Y1
=IFERROR(INDIRECT("AH"&AP3),"") 
new Y2
=INDIRECT("AH"&AQ3) 
X1
=IFERROR(INDIRECT("AD"&AP3),"") 
X2
=IFERROR(INDIRECT("AD"&AQ3),"") 
new velocity (Y)
=IF(AO3<>"",IFERROR(AR3+(AD3-AT3)*(AS3-AR3)/(AU3-AT3),AH3),AH3)
```

[image: steps to interpolate between local maxima]

Hope This helps others.

Answer (score 1):

The `OR` function is what you're looking for. If either of its arguments is true it will output `TRUE`. Your end function will thus look like:

```
=IF(OR(P60=P59,S60<(0.5*S59),S60<(0.5*S58)),"removed",P60) 'there are more arguments in your actual nested function that you will add
```

Comment: Fun fact: the arbitrary length is limited to [`32,767` characters per cell](https://support.office.com/en-nz/article/Excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3).

Comment: user3819867; I still need to add up to 20 arguments in order for the condition to check if S60 is less than 50% of S41 (the last kept value). This is what i was trying to avoid. The OR function does make it a lot simpler though, Thanks.